arrows disappeared in plt.savefig()
I tried to save a figure drawn by plt.quiver() and saved it with plt.savefig(). The figure was saved, but the arrows disappeared. Here's my code:
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
levels = [4, 5, 3, 2]
x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(levels))

for i in range(len(levels) - 1):
    j = i + 1
    n1, n2 = levels[i], levels[j]
    y1, y2 = np.mgrid[0:1:n1*1j, 0:1:n2*1j]
    x1 = np.full_like(y1, x[i])
    x2 = np.full_like(y2, x[j])
    plt.quiver(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1, 
              angles="xy", units="dots", scale_units="xy", 
              scale=1, width=2, headlength=10,
              headaxislength=10, headwidth=4)
    
yp = np.concatenate([np.linspace(0, 1, n) for n in levels])
xp = np.repeat(x, levels)
plt.plot(xp, yp, "o", ms=12)
plt.gca().axis("off")
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.savefig(r'exp\exp4\output\nu.jpg')

Can you help me with it?
I added plt.show() at the end of the code. And then I saw the normal figure:
Normal
But the figure I saved with plt.savefig() is:
The arrows dissappeared
I tried to search the Internet and the matplotlib's doc, but I didn't find the solution.

I cannot reproduce the problem on Linux with Matplotlib v3.8.3.  What Matplotlib version do you have?

Sorry for not providing the detail of the environment. Mine is Matplotlib v3.9.0. and the system is Windows.

I changed the way the way the plot is saved by specifying the format, dpi and the bbox:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
levels = [4, 5, 3, 2]
x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(levels))

for i in range(len(levels) - 1):
    j = i + 1
    n1, n2 = levels[i], levels[j]
    y1, y2 = np.mgrid[0:1:n1*1j, 0:1:n2*1j]
    x1 = np.full_like(y1, x[i])
    x2 = np.full_like(y2, x[j])
    plt.quiver(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1, 
               angles="xy", units="xy", scale_units="xy", 
               scale=1, width=0.005, headlength=10, 
               headaxislength=10, headwidth=4, color='r') 
yp = np.concatenate([np.linspace(0, 1, n) for n in levels])
xp = np.repeat(x, levels)
plt.plot(xp, yp, "o", ms=12)
plt.gca().axis("off")
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)

plt.draw()

plt.savefig(r'nu.jpg', format='jpg', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()

and the plot.show() gave

and the saved image gave


It wouldn't hurt to point out what exactly you changed (kind of a PITA to scroll up and down trying to figure out the few differences), and why that makes a difference. "I did this" is not the greatest explanation.

Thanks! Sorry, I know little of matplotlib and don't know much about what I can try.  I should  have tried harder. I changed the unit and width in the quiver() method to 'xy' and '0.05', then the saved image became normal. It seems that those two args were to blame.
